# Using an i2C OLED display with lgpio and a kernel newer than 5.11

Tags: gpio, kernel

I'm on Ubuntu 23.10 on a RPI 4 and the kernel used here is not compatible with RPI.GPIO because -- as far as I understand -- RPI.GPIO cannot see if multiple processes are trying to use the same pins. lgpio can handle that and the crucial bit is the function lgpio.gpiochip_open that will give you a handle to the pins that your program safely can use. This has been an issue since Linux kernel 5.11 and isn't a problem with Ubuntu *per se*.
So far so good. I've managed to get "the blinking LED" program up and running with lgpio and Python 3.11 in a venv environment, but it seems that all of the popular libraries for small, cheap OLED displays, e.g. Luma or Adafruit, hasn't been updated yet.

Are anybody aware of a library I can use or is there a relative straight forward way to replace RPI.GPIO with lgpio in e.g. the Luma library?

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)